# How to delete file owned by root that has spaces in the name?

Tags: linux, bash, file, shell, root

i recently downloaded a file from terminal on debian 8 jessie.
the file is OWNED by ROOT. i try

```
chown michael Montana Of 300 - Chiraq (Remix) Shot By @AZaeProduction-bA4xvmH3WSQ.mp4
```

but i get

```
   bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

samething with the rm command.

the problem is the file has spaces and a ( in the middle) if the file name.

is there anyway i can delete this?????   all it is, is a mp4 file.   not sure how it got changed to root but anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file name can be quoted "..." or spaces and other special symbols should be escaped by backslash:

```
chown michael Montana\ Of\ 300\ -\ Chiraq\ \(Remix\)\ Shot\ By\ @AZaeProduction-bA4xvmH3WSQ.mp4
chown michael "Montana Of 300 - Chiraq (Remix) Shot By @AZaeProduction-bA4xvmH3WSQ.mp4"
```

It will allow you to pass the file name to `chown` or to other tools. However, if it is owned by `root` to change ownership `chown` should be also called from `root` (e.g. using `sudo`).

Comment: @Michael It is hard to guess how your OS is configured. There are different approaches. Do you have rights to do some operations as root? For example, how do you install packages?

Comment: my friend set the system up for me. dual boot with windows on another harddrive  the unix password was my login password. i su  then password then apt-get  blah blah.  ive just never got sudo to work and ive been wondering why.

Comment: @Michael I guess that you already found that here `su` is the option. Instead of `apt-get ...` just do `chown...`